# PHP Warning when using include_once()

Tags: php

When I try to include a file using include_once in php which shows warning like

> Warning: include_once(1) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test/content_box.php on line 2

Actually file is there in my directory.I am using ubuntu (OS)
How can we prevent this warning?

Comment: (1)? What's that? at least put the extension on that [include_once('1.php')];

Comment: Surely, by 'prevent warning' you mean how to properly include the file, no?

Comment: @Ben it is more likely boolean result of some function, being cast to a string :)

Comment: @OP - You should listen to Col. Shrapnel ^ up here

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Note**: *My answer below has turned out to be popular, but I didn't really answer the question properly.  It's not about suppressing the warning, it's about fixing the bug that caused the warning.  I'll leave it here for posterity.*

---

The proper way to prevent the warning would be to check if the first exists first and don't try to include it if it doesn't.

```
if (file_exists($includefile)) {
  include_once($includefile);
}
```

(obviously replace $includefile with the file you're including)

The quick and dirty way to do it, which I **DO NOT** recommend, would be to suppress the warning with the @ expression.

```
@include_once($includefile);
```

Note that when suppressing a warning this way, PHP's error handling code still runs but with PHP's error_reporting ini value temporarily changed to ignore it.  As a rule of thumb this isn't a good idea because it can mask other errors.

*As others have pointed out, "1" is an unusual filename for a PHP file, but I'll assume you have a specific reason for doing that.*

Comment: first one is subject to discuss but second one is terrible

Comment: Which is why I used it as an example of what not to do.

Comment: looks like you just took this question too literally. that's big SO problem. everyone just answer a question, not trying to think it out a bit -  what caused this question, are there other interpretations?

Comment: If you read my answer you would see that I am clearly explaining that using @ is not a good idea.  I don't get it???

Comment: Answer modified to make it even more clear that I am not recommending using @ for those who didn't read my whole answer.

Comment: Who are you talking to exactly?  I can assure you I do understand PHP error handling.  Why are you acting as if I was claiming @ to be a good idea?  I never claimed that.  Using @ can mask other errors in your code, which is why you shouldn't use it.  I dunno maybe I'm making the mistake of feeding the trolls here.  If you can tell me where you think my answer is wrong, I will fix it.  If you just degrade me without pointing out the specifics, then I can't do anything.

Comment: Meh I'm not going to keep fighting you.  This is ridiculous.

Comment: I think this may be a linguistic issue.. @Col. Shrapnel seems to have a poor grasp of English grammar.

Comment: @intuited perhaps. But I have good grasp of logic. If you think something is bad - do not recommend it at all.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: My point is that you seem to be misreading his original statement.  The first four words of the phrase "The quick and dirty way to do it" are logically essential to the subsequent ones.  Someone with strong English grammar skils would realize this, and would generally conclude that this was "**NOT**" a recommendation for any situation where another approach is possible.  Perhaps the issue is not so much grammar as idiom comprehension.  "Quick and dirty" is generally considered undesirable unless you are desperate.

Comment: @intuited So what I say - even if you desperate there are always proper solution. So, not a single reason to mention a dirty one. Especially in the given context, where not error message but error itself were asked to eliminate.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: The OP said "prevent this warning".  This is ambiguous: it could mean that the goal was to resolve the issue that was creating the warning, or that it was to silence the warning itself.  @thomasrutter answered both of the possible interpretations, with the caveat that silencing the warning is not a good idea.  In the broader sense, there are some situations where it is useful to silence warnings, so it's good to let people know of this language feature, but important to make sure that it's not misapplied.

Comment: @intuited no, he didn't resolve the issue that was creating the warning. To resolve it, a proper filename must be set. And silencing is not an option at all, even if the OP meant it. If someone asks you how to shoot himself in a leg, it will be stupid to explain and then follow with a warning. And this case is not a situation where it is useful to silence.

Comment: "In the broader sense, there are some situations where it is useful to silence warnings, so it's good to let people know of this language feature, but important to make sure that it's not misapplied."   For example, when you begin applying a hacksaw to your leg, a warning is issued (pain).  However if you know in advance that there is an incurable case of gangrene in that leg, or that it is chained to a post in a pit containing a sleeping Vogon, then it is important to silence the warning from your nervous system, eg by using an anaesthetic. Otherwise your anguished screams may wake the Vogon.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I do agree with you though that this doesn't really resolve the root issue, it just prevents a warning from being issued.  In some situations (eg attempting to include an optional module/library file) the approach of checking for the presence of the include file would be appropriate.  However this doesn't seem to be the case here.  It sounds like you're right, that a function is being called to get the include file name and that this is being done incorrectly.  We'll have to wait to see if the OP posts some code.

Comment: It should be noted, that include will look in your include path, but file_exists will not...so this isn't a holistic solution

Comment: Good point: this solution kind of requires the include filename to be an absolute path (that or a file in the current working directory).

Comment: if include_path is relied upon, you may want to try the `file_exists()` test on each item of the former. You may want to  use `foreach(explode(':', ini_get('include_path')) as $dir)` around your test.

Comment: FYI, suppressing the warning with @ no longer works in PHP 8.

Answer (score 9):

Obviously the issue here is that PHP can't find the file you're trying to include. To reduce confusion about what the current path is, I usually make it an absolute path like this:

```
// inc.php is in the same directory:
include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/inc.php");

// inc.php is in a subdirectory
include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/folder/inc.php");

// inc.php is in a parent directory
include (dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "inc.php");
```

It's probably a bit over the top, but you can be sure to know where PHP is looking for your files.

Comment: Or use `__DIR__` if you've got PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

that's quite unusual name for the php file - a single digit `1`.
are you sure you have such a file?

Answer (score -1):

You're probably trying a statement such as this:

```
include('header.php') or die('Include file not found.');
```

In this case what's happening is operator precedence is evaluating it like this:

```
include ( ('header.php') or die('Include file not found.') );
```

And because the string `'header.php'` does not evaluate to false, it's being cast to a `1` in this context.

You can fix this by rearranging parentheses:

```
(include 'header.php') or die('Include file not found.');
```

Note that `include` is a keyword rather than a function call so no parentheses are required for its argument.