# PHP Handling script inclusion without supressing its errors and warning

Tags: php, apache, http, error-handling

I'm trying to guess how to achieve scripts inclusions and keep it throwing errors and warnings. I've got the following code:

```
if(!@include_once "myscript.php") doSomething();
```

This will supress "include" warning error if script file doesn't exist and it will include the script file if it exists. The problem comes when an error is generated in "myscript.php". For example, I've got another `require_once` in "myscript.php" and I caused an error by setting a wrong path. Errors are not displayed and code after that call is not reached/executed.

Is there a way I can supress just the file inclusion errors but not errors generated in the included script? If not, what other way can I use to achieve the target behaviour?

I've thought about using `file_exists` function to check if script file exists and then include it if `TRUE` but I'm looking for the simplest way.

I'll put a practical example since it's difficult to understand the actual question:

Imagine that we want to manage a file system that will be used by a user and we need to check whether the user has created a file because that file will be included after the check, but we want to handle the inclusion warning/error so we can show a message or log the warning in a custom log file. First function that comes to our mind is to use `file_exists` and then `include` that file. Well, by using `@include` both functions are performing, it will check if the file exists and it will include the file and that's what I'm researching, the simplest way of doing an action. This way of doing it has an undesired behaviour: it supresses the errors/warnings generated by the included file, not only the inclusion errors/warnings itself. Other reason to avoid `file_exists` when you are checking if a file exists before trying to include it may be that the way both functions look for a file are different and they may generate different results because of `include_path`. Is this correct?

Comment: Using `file_exists()` is not simple? :P

Comment: file_exists doesn't work like include / require (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672572/php-warning-when-using-include-once)

Comment: can you provide more context about what you are trying to accomplish?  typically router style implementations solve this with file_exists check, but an autoloader may also be appropriate.

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran that would imply to use `file_exists` and `include`. It's better to use just one function if possible :D

Comment: Don't suppress errors. Fix the code so that it doesn't generate them.

Comment: @xeo I know `file_exists` doesn't work like `include`. My question is if there's a way to supress inclusion error if file doesn't exists but not errors produced in code typed in that file.

Comment: @Sammitch sorry if you didn't understand the question. I'm not trying to do "hacks" to hide errors, I'm trying to handle inclusions.

Comment: Yeah and see that part at the end of your question where you answered your own question, but also said that you didn't want to do it? Do that. PHP doesn't have a built-in for every esoteric, ill-advised thing anyone might ever feel like doing.

Comment: @Sammitch The question is if there's a way of doing it by using `@` and `include` so I didn't answer my own question, I just wanted to put is as an alternative and a way to explain what I'm trying to do from other way. It seems that my will to learn and find different ways to do things offend you. Thanks for your answer "Do that", you should have answered that from the beginning.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the error from `include()` itself?

Comment: @Barmar I want to handle it the way `file_exists` does. By handling `@include` I do both operations: check if file exists and include it. The only undesired behaviour is that it supresses errors produced by included script. Is my question ridiculous? :S

Comment: You can use `file_exists`, but it won't search the directories in `include_path` like `include` and `require` do.

Comment: The question isn't ridiculous, it's just strange. Why do you want to show all errors except the ones from `include` not being able to find the file?

Comment: @Barmar question updated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`stream_resolve_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php) to process the filename the way `include` does, and then check this with `file_exists`. So:

```
if (file_exists($path) || file_exists(stream_resolve_include_path($path)) {
    include($path);
}
```

The first `file_exists()` call is in case the pathname is absolute, which overrides the `include_path` setting.